# Laravel eloquent build query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to write a query using the Laravel Eloquent structure. I want to query these values ​​after entering the min and max values. I have a product table. Column product table with discount (%) and price. I want to get min and max value according to the discounted value of the product.

I want this to be based on the query including the discount.

```php
$products->where('price', '<=', $max)
  ->where('price', '>=', $min)
  ->orderByDesc('id')
  ->paginate(9);
```

Product migration:

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('upper_category_id')->index();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->index();
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
  $table->string('name');
  $table->longText('text');
  $table->float('price')->index();
  $table->integer('stock');
  $table->float('discount');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

*Thank you very much in advance.*

Comment: If you're just asking for Eloquent, then you could write the SQL query for your problem, then we can help to to convert that to Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you can try do it this way:

```php
$products->where(DB::raw('price - price * discount'), '<=', $max)
  ->where(DB::raw('price - price * discount'), '>=', $min)
  ->orderByDesc('id')
  ->paginate(9);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions